# Error using Microsoft Access Input to read .mdb file with Spoon

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to read an Access database file, .mdb file with Spoon,
using Microsoft Access Input in Design tab.
But it is not working.

When I press Get Tables in Content tab I get this error: Looking for usage map at page 32000, but page type is 0

If I put one table and press preview rows I get this error:

> 019/08/27 11:35:32 - Spoon - Spoon
>   2019/08/27 11:52:22 - /Transformación 1 - Iniciado despacho de la transformación [/Transformación 1]
>   2019/08/27 11:52:22 - Microsoft Access Input.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Couldn't open file #1 : file:///home/pentaho/Escritorio/general.mdb --> java.io.IOException: Looking for usage map at page 32000, but page type is 0
>   2019/08/27 11:52:22 - Microsoft Access Input.0 - Procesamiento finalizado (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
>   2019/08/27 11:52:22 - /Transformación 1 - Transformación detectada 
>   2019/08/27 11:52:22 - /Transformación 1 - Transformación esta matando los otros pasos!

Thank you.

Comment: I had same problem  but it had been solved ,by just rewriting  file path in microsoft access input.

Comment: Yes it works for me too. I think the .mdb file was corrupted.